# Android MatrixCursor

Tags: android, matrixcursor

I am trying to get a basic matrix cursor running, but for some reason the list remains empty. Would appreciate if someone could spot what may be wrong with the code?

```
    String []columns = new String[] {"_id","Title","Desc"} ;
    MatrixCursor mc = new MatrixCursor(columns);
    startManagingCursor(mc);

    for(int i=0; i< 200;i++)
    {
        mc.addRow(new Object[]{i, "test"+i ,"..."});
    }

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.alist);

    int [] r = new int[1];
    r[0] = R.id.atext;           // the id of the textview in test_list_item layout
    String [] s= new String[1];  
    s[0] = mc.getColumnName(1);  // the column to be used "Title"
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.test_list_item,mc,s,r);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Post the error message if available

Comment: No error message it just displays an empty list...

Comment: this should work but double check your cursor: DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor

Comment: dumpCursor showed that the contents was there within the cursor, but for some reason is not being displayed in the list view?

Comment: Thanks fellas, I made stupid mistake, I was using one of the default layouts not my own so the above should have been ..(this,R.layout... instead of ..(this,android.R.layout.. Again cheers for taking time to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the layout was not read was due to  the incorrect layout being called:
           SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.list_item,mc,s,r);
Instead of:
           SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.my_list_item,mc,s,r);